# What is the right syntax to the decision tree using the Con statement or any other method to classify?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

[image]

Can you please show me how to construct the decision tree for the attached land cover classification.
I assume it is nested Con statement, but I am confused on how to write the statement.

Comment: is your data vector or raster (probably raster if you mention Con, but just to make sure) ?

Comment: My data is raster ( DEM Image, Precipitation, etc.)

Answer (score 5):

The con statement has the following syntax :

```
Con ( condition, value_if_true , value_if_false)
```

A "one liner" would be very long, but possible. However it is sometimes better to do several steps.

Here is a start, to give you the idea: the main difficulty is then to place the parentheses at the right place.

```
Con ( "AET" < 0.4 ,  Con ("AET" < 0.15 , 1 , 2 ) , Con ( "MTCM" < 17 , 3 , Con ( "to_be_continued") )  )
```

1 is for desert, 2 is for semi-Arid, 3 is for mountain... (you store integers in rasters, you can create a look up table after).

"AET" is an example of name, you can use the layer name or the full path)

Comment: ,thanks for the help. i had the raster but it is coarse resolution. How can we use vector data (shapefile) for the same decision-tree?

Comment: for vector, you should post another question and describe your input data in order to get an appropriate answer, and to fit with the QA rules of this site.

Answer (score 0):

If your datasets are vector consider using the Union tool. The output will have all combinations of polygons with the original attribution. I am assuming you have the advanced level license.

Then you could create some sort of nested if-then field calculation to assign the land type.